# Can zookeeper be used as load balancer instead of Nginx or Apache Server?

Tags: tomcat, nginx, load-balancing, apache-zookeeper

Currently, i have two tomcat server and some restful webservices are deployed on them.

And i got a Nginx server to do the load-balancing work to distribute http request sent from browser via ajax to one of the tomcat servers.

My first question is whether i can use zookeeper as load balancer instead of Nginx? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ZooKeeper out of the box, you would have to design and code your own load balancing on top of ZooKeeper.

ZooKeeper for load balancing usually makes sense when you are already using it for service discovery, e.g. getting endpoints for your services. In this case you can also add load balancing to your application. You can also add additional health information and than do much smarter and application specific load balancing than with lower level load balancers.

ZK is not your standard load balancing solution and cannot be simply plugged in to your existing stack instead of another more specialized load balancer or frontend/proxy server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.